# tweenjs .call() called to soon

Tags: typescript, do.call

the onComplete Method that is inside of .call is called to soon. It should be called only at the end.

code

```
createjs.Tween.get(this).to({filled: 1}, duration).addEventListener("change", () => { this.renderFill(color)}).call(onComplete());
```

I tried to add a .wait() before call, but it gave an exception.

this one works neither. the onComplete-method is called before the tween ends his work.

```
createjs.Tween.get(this).to({filled: 1}, duration).wait(duration).call(onComplete()).addEventListener("change", () => { this.renderFill(color)});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `call` expects a function that *it will call* ... so don't call it. i.e. `onComplete` not `onComplete()`

```
createjs.Tween.get(this).to({filled: 1}, duration).addEventListener("change", () => { this.renderFill(color)}).call(onComplete);
```

Comment: onComplete is not called in the first sample, but in the second one, it works fine. thanks!